# Vue.js: Collapse of a single div

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to collapse a single div with Vue, without any additional add-ons like BootstrapVue? If so, how do I do?

**[This example is from the mentioned addon](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/collapse/):**

```
<div>
  <b-btn v-b-toggle.collapse1 variant="primary">Toggle Collapse</b-btn>
  <b-collapse id="collapse1" class="mt-2">
    <b-card>
      <p class="card-text">Collapse contents Here</p>
      <b-btn v-b-toggle.collapse1_inner size="sm">Toggle Inner Collapse</b-btn>
      <b-collapse id=collapse1_inner class="mt-2">
        <b-card>Hello!</b-card>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-card>
  </b-collapse>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store a data value e.g. `display_div` with initial value of `true`. Then, in your div tag have `<div v-if="display_div">` or `<div v-show="display_div">`. Finally, your button should handle toggling the `display_div` value, e.g. `<input type="button" value="Toggle Collapse" v-on:click="display_div = !display_div"/>`.

You could also move your toggle logic into its own method e.g. `toggleDiv()` and your method could look like this:

```
toggleDiv: function() {
    this.display_div = !this.display_div;
}
```

Full example:

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-if="display_div">Test</div>
    <input type="button" value="Toggle Collapse" v-on:click="toggleDiv()"/>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            display_div: false
        },
        methods: {
            toggleDiv: function() {
                this.display_div = !this.display_div;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want animated collapse/ expand like bootstrap 4.x does, you can use the following directive. `Bootstrap.css` is required but `jQuery` or `Bootstrap.js` is not required. This solution adds `collapsing` css class to add the animation.

```
Vue.directive('collapsible', {
   bind: function (el, binding) {        
      el.transitionDuration = 350;
   },
   update: function (el, binding) {        
      if (binding.oldValue != binding.value){
          if (binding.value) {      
             setTimeout(function () {
                 el.classList.remove("collapse");                    
                 var height = window.getComputedStyle(el).height;                    
                 el.classList.add('collapsing');
                 el.offsetHeight;
                 el.style.height = height;
                 setTimeout(function() {                
                    el.classList.remove("collapsing");
                    el.classList.add('collapse');                   
                    el.style.height = null;                        
                    el.classList.add('show');                    
                }, el.transitionDuration)
             }, 0);
          } 
          else {                
             el.style.height = window.getComputedStyle(el).height;                
             el.classList.remove("collapse");
             el.classList.remove('show');
             el.offsetHeight;
             el.style.height = null;            
             el.classList.add('collapsing');
             setTimeout(function() {                
                el.classList.add('collapse');                
                el.classList.remove("collapsing");                                               
             }, el.transitionDuration)
          }
      }
   }
});
```

How to Use:

```
<button v-on:click="displayDiv = !displayDiv;" class="btn btn-primary"> Click Me                     
</button>
<div class="collapse" v-collapsible="displayDiv">
  Some text <br/>
  More text <br/>
  More text... <br/>
</div>
```

See it [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrjde391/3/)